# Using 'stand for' in reference to acronyms

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I read that 'stand for' means 'To represent; symbolize,' and now I'm wondering whether it can be used in reference to an acronym.

For example, is it proper English the following question ...

'Can you tell me what D.S.J. stands for?'

... in order to ask what 'D', 'S' and 'J' mean?

I'm asking because it is unclear to me what the difference between 'to mean' and 'to represent' (or 'to symbolize') is.

To me, a more natural way to ask the above question would be ...

'Can you tell me what D.S.J. means?'

'to mean' seems to me more proper than 'to stand for' which I would use almost only if an abstract concept, rather than an acronym, is involved.

Comment: Interesting perspective, Elberich.  To my AmE ear, it sounds just a tad off to ask _"what does D.S.J. mean"_ because the letters _mean_ nothing..., they have no inherent meaning.  These letters _represent_ or _stand for_ some words, which have an inherent meaning.  Having said this, one might ask the question using either Vern phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, IBM stands  for International business machines .

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The sentence is valid and means as you described it.